# How to handle 'connection has timed out' in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For Ex, I am accessing url in selenium Webdriver, its showing as 'connection has timed out' but my code keep on executes & trying to find mail-Id, its not throwing any exception and showing error as

> 'Unable to locate element:{"method":"id","selector":"hotel_dest"}'

```
driver.get("http://192.168.0.151/holidaysonclick/");  
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
driver.findElement(By.id("mail")).clear();
```

How to handle this Issue,

Comment: Hi senthilvel, and welcome to stack overflow. The error message 'connection has timed out' - is that what the web server returns to the browser, or is that the error from your webdriver test?

Comment: @vincebowdren Hi, that error is return from web server to browser, in firefox it will show as 'connection has timed out'.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to increase the timeout to ensure that the objects are available to selenium to work.
If you want to handle the error, better include this code in @BeforeTest or @BeforeSuite annotation which ensure the entire test suite will not run if this fails.
You can also use try/catch to catch the error and throw exception. Choose whatever is best solution in your case

Comment: All good advice. I particularly recommend implementing a `TestWatcher` class to make sure that, when any testcase fails for any reason, it takes a screenshot and records the DOM state.

Comment: @Affi As you mentioned i have include this code in @BeforeSuite, but my code trying to find mail-Id, shows error as 'Unable to locate element:{"method":"id","selector":"hotel_dest"}'
Example of Code :
`@BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() 
  {
    driver.get("http://192.168.0.151/holidaysonclick/");  
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 }
  @Test
  public void f() 
  {
  driver.findElement(By.id("mail")).clear();
  }`

Comment: Is it working if you put everything in the @Test?? If yes, then try moving the driver.get() part to @Test. For example: a)BeforeSuite 
public void beforeSuite() { 
WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} 
a)Test 
public void f() { 
driver.get("http://192.168.0.151/holidaysonclick/"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("mail")).clear();

Comment: @Affi As per your suggestion I have included code in `@Before Suite`, it should throw timeout error in this method but its running next test suite and showing error as `Unable to locate element:`. Any solution to handle this.

Comment: You should only use Before Suite for initialization, not for entire code. You can define separate functions to handle errors like `code`     public static Boolean IsObjectExists(WebDriver driver, By locator){
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  try{   
   driver.findElement(locator);
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   return true;
   
  } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   return false;
  } `code`